# Populate Ember.Select directly from Database

Tags: javascript, ajax, ember.js

Let me explain my issue, I am trying to populate `Ember.Select` directly from database.

I have these routes:

```
       this.resource('twod', function() {
            this.resource('twoduser', {
                path : ':user_id'
            });
        });
```

In `twoduser`, I am displaying a full information about a single user. In that view, I have a Select Box as well, which end user will select and then with a button, he can add the user to a team that he selected from Ember.Select.

I tried to do this,

```
App.TwoduserController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    selectedTeam : null,
    team : function (){
        var teams = [];
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : "http://pioneerdev.us/users/getTeamNames",
            data : data,
            success : function (data){
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i ++){
                    var teamNames = data[i];
                    teams.push(teamNames);
                }
            }
        });
       return teams;
    }.property()
})
```

Then in my `index.html`:

```
         {{view Ember.Select
    contentBinding="team"
    optionValuePath="teams.team_name"
    optionLabelPath="teams.team_name"
    selectionBinding="selectedTeam"
    prompt="Please Select a Team"}}
```

But when I do this, for some reason it interferes with `Twoduser` and I am not able to view the single user.

Furthermore, here's a sample `JSON` response I will get through the url:

```
{"teams":[{"team_name":"Toronto Maple Leafs"},{"team_name":"Vancouver Canuck"}]}
```

Moreover, I am fetching all users using **Ajax** like this:

```
App.Twod.reopenClass({
    findAll : function() {

        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            $.getJSON("http://pioneerdev.us/users/index", function(data) {
                var result = data.users.map(function(row) {
                    return App.Twod.create(row);
                });
                resolve(result);
            }).fail(reject);
        });
    },
    findBy : function(user_id) {

        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var user = App.Twod.create();
            $.getJSON("http://pioneerdev.us/users/byId/" + user_id, function(data) {
                var result = user.setProperties(data.user);
                resolve(result);
            }).fail(reject);
        });
    }
});
```

Though there's one thing, I have a separate `Teams` route:

```
this.resource('teamview', function(){
            this.resource('teamviewdetail', {
                path : ':team_id'
            });
        });
```

Which shows all the teams and a single team when you click on a single team.

Can I use that `TeamviewController`? or Can I fetch team names from `Twoduser` Controller and push names to the array as I mentioned before?

More Information:

If I use the way I mentioned, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addArrayObserver'
```

Here's a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ankurk/qgcB7/) on the issue I am experiencing. You can select "Storyboard" from the Designation & then select the user. That will reproduce the issue.

One more **Update**: Seems using `ObjectController` instead of `ArrayController` issue solves the addArrayObserver issue. But still I can't get the teams in the Ember.Select.

Comment: App.TwoduserController.team needs a `return teams;` line

Comment: If I use this method, I get the error, Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addArrayObserver'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest issue here is that you use `Array#push` instead of `pushObject`. Ember needs the special methods in order to be aware of changes. Otherwise, it will continue to think that the array of teams is as empty as when you first returned it. Second biggest issue is that your ajax `success` call isn't accessing the returned data properly.

Also, `optionValuePath` and `optionLabelPath` are relative to the individual select option view, so they should start with `content`, which is the individual item as set on the view. So: `content.team_name`

Comment: If you check my fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/qgcB7/3/. I tried using `pushObject`. Something else might be wrong.